# What are the necessary packages for build , compile application and install it by creating make file?

Tags: make, configure

I want to install packages with using  make file. What are the necessary packages for build ,compile package and install make file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`build_essential` to start with. Then you can install necessary dependancies/support libraries based off `apt-get build-dep`, or the error messages from `./configure`.

If you want to grow together a quick and dirty deb for install, use `checkinstall` instead of `make install`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make a "make file" or compile it?

If it's for writing a make file: gedit or your preferred editor.

If it's for compilation, it's easy: gcc, g++, make, devtools (or maybe dev-tools or development-tools).

Comment: or just build-essential

Comment: just build-essential